# Ubuntu Mate time synchronisation issue

Tags: ubuntu-mate, date, ntp

I can't manage to fix the time on the Ubuntu Mate I have installed on a Raspberry Pi3.
"timedatectl" reports

```
      Local time: Tue 2018-02-20 15:30:22 GMT
      Universal time: Tue 2018-02-20 15:30:22 UTC
      RTC time: n/a
      Time zone: Europe/London (GMT, +0000)
      Network time on: yes
      NTP synchronized: no
      RTC in local TZ: no
```

which is clearly some days back in time. I have tried to install and start the NTP service but it seems like it can't syncronise. "ntpq -p" reports:

```
          remote           refid      st t when poll reach   delay   offset  jitter
      ==============================================================================
  0.ubuntu.pool.n .POOL.          16 p    -   64    0    0.000    0.000   0.002
  1.ubuntu.pool.n .POOL.          16 p    -   64    0    0.000    0.000   0.002
  2.ubuntu.pool.n .POOL.          16 p    -   64    0    0.000    0.000   0.002
  3.ubuntu.pool.n .POOL.          16 p    -   64    0    0.000    0.000   0.002
  ntp.ubuntu.com  .POOL.          16 p    -   64    0    0.000    0.000   0.002
```

But I understand that the delay offset and jitter values should be meaningful number instead of zero.
"ntpstat" also reports "unsynchronized" status.

"systemctl status ntp" reports:

```
● ntp.service - LSB: Start NTP daemon
  Loaded: loaded (/etc/init.d/ntp; bad; vendor preset: enabled)
  Active: active (running) since Tue 2018-02-20 15:37:19 GMT; 7min ago
  Docs: man:systemd-sysv-generator(8)
  CGroup: /system.slice/ntp.service
         └─6732 /usr/sbin/ntpd -p /var/run/ntpd.pid -g -u 109:118

  Feb 20 15:42:46 turtlebot-desktop ntpd[6732]: Soliciting pool server 2a03:b980:123:2::a
  Feb 20 15:42:48 turtlebot-desktop ntpd[6732]: Soliciting pool server 87.124.126.49
  Feb 20 15:42:54 turtlebot-desktop ntpd[6732]: Soliciting pool server 185.182.62.7
  Feb 20 15:42:55 turtlebot-desktop ntpd[6732]: Soliciting pool server 2001:67c:1560:8003::c8
  Feb 20 15:43:46 turtlebot-desktop ntpd[6732]: Soliciting pool server 213.130.44.252
  Feb 20 15:43:52 turtlebot-desktop ntpd[6732]: Soliciting pool server 2001:67c:16d0::2
  Feb 20 15:43:52 turtlebot-desktop ntpd[6732]: Soliciting pool server 213.251.53.217
  Feb 20 15:43:58 turtlebot-desktop ntpd[6732]: Soliciting pool server 162.213.34.249
  Feb 20 15:44:02 turtlebot-desktop ntpd[6732]: Soliciting pool server 91.189.89.198
  Feb 20 15:44:52 turtlebot-desktop ntpd[6732]: Soliciting pool server 178.79.152.182
```

Any idea of the reason ?

Comment: Your clock is too wrong.  `ntp` can't correct instantly as this could cause programs to crash/give-wrong-output if instantly changed, so ntp corrects time slowly.... If 'ntp' detects its too far-out, it can quit and will throw messages asking operator to correct manually (look for these).  I would suggest manually correcting (ntp will take too long; its purpose is to keep time accurate, not set date/time)

Comment: Thank you, I actually don't get any "manual fix suggestion", still I will give it a try

Comment: the 'messages' are unlikely to have been on screen, but in logs on your system.

Comment: I've manually modified the time but nothing seems like changing